# Concat two columns With laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, concatenation

I have 3 tables, 1. countries 2. states 3.citites

**COUNTRIES** contains id, name columns .

**STATES** contains id, name, country_id columns.

**CITIES** contains id, name, state_id.

I am accessing cities with hasManyThrough() relation.

Relation:

```
public function cities()
{
   return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\City','App\Models\State');
}
```

How i am fetching citeis:

```
$countryObj = Country::where('name','like',$country.'%')->first();
$cities =  $countryObj->cities->pluck('name');
return response()->json(['cities'=>$cities],200);
```

I want to **concat** cites with theirs respective countries. Like: **Uk-London**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use [map](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-map). You can pass the `$countryObj` in to it and then simply concatenate the strings together:

```
$countryObj = Country::where('name', 'like', $country . '%')->first();

$cities = $countryObj->cities->map(function ($city) use ($countryObj) {
    return $countryObj->name . '-' . $city->name;
});

return response()->json(['cities' => $cities], 200);
```

Comment: What if i want to concat each cities with their country. Like: UK-London,US-New york,...

Comment: @weaver You could eager load the states and countries with the cities and then use map again.